# Automated testing to check the value in a table cell - Django.

Tags: django, testing, integration

My Django app is in need of some automated testing.

Many of the views produce tabular data (from a generic list view). I have created fixtures to test some of the more complex cases that have been causing subtle bugs.

What should I be using to test the value in a specific table cell (or column)?

There seems to be a lot of testing tools / libraries out there django-test client, Selenium, Nose. A lot of things seem to be aimed at unit testing (while I am not finding so many bugs at this level). I am looking more to integration testing. Reading all the documentation for all the libraries is going to take a while to find what I want.

So can someone advise what libraries / tools I should use to check the final output values in my list view's tabular output? I would like to give a URL, and confirm that the page returned has a value in particular row / column is equal to  my expected value.

Comment: Selenium is very firmly aimed at integration testing, not unit testing.

Answer (score -1):

> There seems to be a lot of testing tools / libraries out there django-test client, Selenium, Nose. A lot of things seem to be aimed at unit testing (while I am not finding so many bugs at this level). I am looking more to integration testing.

It works very well for integration testing. Maybe you would have found out if you had tried ? Maybe it's time for you to (re?) read about the correct [hacker attitude](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html)

Also, I've been having loads of [fun with ghost.py](https://gist.github.com/jpic/074a1a54181f50d578dc)

> Reading all the documentation for all the libraries is going to take a while to find what I want.

It's your work to do research as well. Believe it or not it took me like 5 hours to check all solutions yesterday and decide to go with ghost.py and get it to work nicely with django (hence the gist upload !).

But yeah, if you don't want to learn anything new then you're stuck at "Not knowing out to do integration testing". If you want to learn "how to make integration testing" then you have to do research. There's no secret my friend :)

Comment: I want to learn how to do it properly, but most of the documentation I come across is testing really basic stuff. I was hoping people here may have had similar problems and be able to point me in the right direction.
Is it the case that I should build up tests like I should with code starting with basic units and building it together to something big? If so then it is likely to take far longer to write the tests that the code, and I doubt my managers would be happy with me spending so much time on it.

Comment: Do your managers care about quality insurance ? Do they want php-style quality or google-style quality ? Can't the ghost snippet I sent you help you get started ? Here's an [example with selenium](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/tests/widget.py) which I hope to get rid of in favor of Ghost.py before django-autocomplete-light 2.0 (June) maybe it will help you. One thing is certain: nobody here is going to do your work.

Comment: Unfortunately management don't seem to care about quality very much (it is a research centre, not a coding house)! 
That's why I am trying to get testing up and running quickly.

Comment: And I don't really see how asking for some advice implies I want someone to do my work for me.

Comment: So, what are you coding your integration tests with after all ? I'm curious :)

Comment: Note: maybe the easiest for you is to use iMacro.

Comment: I want to start using automated tests, hence asking what libraries people recommend. I have some very basic ones with the django test client, but i am struggling to see an efficient way to use this for the test cases I have described. Looking at the Ghost.py documentation just now. Will iMacro integrate with other tools easily (Jenkins for example).